# SQLite: Unable to print all rows

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have build an Android application, where I'm using Sqlite Database.
Here I have written a getAllContacts, and i want to print all rows in a for loop.

But when I have stored 5rows of data, and when getAllContacts  is executed, only the last row data are printed, but not the rest(Please Help me in printing all rows). I don't understand where i have gone wrong, please Correct me.
**Thank You in Advance**

Here is my DataBaseCOde :

```
public List<SqlContact> getAllContacts() {
    List<SqlContact> contactList = new ArrayList<SqlContact>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            SqlContact contact = new SqlContact();

            contact.setId((cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setDescription(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setMessage(cursor.getString(2));
            contact.setStatus(cursor.getString(3));
            contact.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(4));
            contact.setType(cursor.getString(5));

            contactList.add(contact);


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


    return contactList;
}
```

Here is my Activity Code (For loop to print all Rows) :

```
                SqlDatabaseNotification db = new SqlDatabaseNotification(getApplicationContext());


                List<SqlContact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
                for (SqlContact cn : contacts) {

                    String log = "Id: " + cn.getStatus() + " ,Description: " + cn.getDescription() + " ,Message: " + cn.getMessage() + " ,Status: " + cn.getStatus()
                            + " ,TimeStamp: " + cn.getTimestamp() + " ,Type: " + cn.getType();
                    // Writing Contacts to log
                    Log.d("Name: ", log);



                }
```

Complete SQLITEDATABASE :

```
public class SqlDatabaseNotification extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
    public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_MESSAGE = "message";
    private HashMap hp;


    public SqlDatabaseNotification(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "create table contacts " +
                        "(id integer primary key, description text,message text,status text, timestamp text,type text)"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addContact(SqlContact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("id", contact.getID());
        contentValues.put("description", contact.getDescription());
        contentValues.put("message", contact.getMessage());
        contentValues.put("status", contact.getStatus());
        contentValues.put("timestamp", contact.getTimestamp());
        contentValues.put("type", contact.getType());
        db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);


        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


    SqlContact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, new String[]{CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID,
                        CONTACTS_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, CONTACTS_COLUMN_MESSAGE, CONTACTS_COLUMN_STATUS, CONTACTS_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, CONTACTS_COLUMN_TYPE}, CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        SqlContact contact = new SqlContact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
        // return contact

        return contact;
    }


    public List<SqlContact> getAllContacts() {
        List<SqlContact> contactList = new ArrayList<SqlContact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME;
//        closeDB();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);



        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                SqlContact contact = new SqlContact();

                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt((cursor.getString(0))));
                contact.setDescription(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setMessage(cursor.getString(2));
                contact.setStatus(cursor.getString(3));
                contact.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(4));
                contact.setType(cursor.getString(5));

                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);


            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    public void closeDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        if (db != null && db.isOpen())
            db.close();
    }

    public int updateContact(SqlContact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID, contact.getID());
        values.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, contact.getDescription());
        values.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_STATUS, contact.getStatus());
        values.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, contact.getTimestamp());
        values.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_TYPE, contact.getType());
        values.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_MESSAGE, contact.getMessage());

        // updating row
        return db.update(CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, values, CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getStatus())});
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(SqlContact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.execSQL("delete from " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME);


//        db.delete(CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
//                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getStatus()) });
        db.close();
    }

    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

My Contacts Class:

```
public class SqlContact {

    private int _id;
    private String description;
    private String message;
    private String status;
    private String timestamp;
    private String type;

    public SqlContact(int id, String description, String message, String status, String timestamp, String type) {

        this._id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.message = message;
        this.status = status;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.type = type;

    }


    public SqlContact() {

    }


    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your SqlContact file here. There is a high chance you have made all its data members as static which is causing this issue.

Comment: have you check how much size of your arraylist?

Comment: Yep i have added as requested

Comment: @RajivReddy show `SqlContact `

Comment: @RajivReddy No you haven't. I didn't need your DB file. I need your Class file SqlContact

Comment: @ra log cursor.getCount() inside getAllContacts()..and make sure its size..

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya...pls check the update now.

Comment: @RajivReddy Check my answer now. Its your id issue

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your if and do statement, and replacing it with your while logic.  The cursor will iterate through all the data.  You only need moveToFirst if you are specifically looking for that portion of your data.

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        SqlContact contact = new SqlContact();

        contact.setId((cursor.getString(0)));
        contact.setDescription(cursor.getString(1));
        contact.setMessage(cursor.getString(2));
        contact.setStatus(cursor.getString(3));
        contact.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(4));
        contact.setType(cursor.getString(5));

        contactList.add(contact);



}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, your logic and his logic are the same.

Comment: Ahh, you got it.

Comment: Nope still same

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor of `SqlContact` class, you are not setting the id correctly which is used to define the uniqueness of your record in your database when you insert.

```
public SqlContact(String id, String description, String message, String status, String timestamp, String type){

        this.setDescription(getId());
        this.setDescription(description);
        this.setMessage(message);
        this.setStatus(status);
        this.setTimestamp(timestamp);
        this.setType(type);

    }
```

You are setting Description twice.

Change

```
this.setDescription(getId());
```

to

```
this.setId(id);
```

Also check your logic, the delete logic tries to take an empty SqlContact so it wont be able to delete anything plus the delete query has a where clause comparing id to status hence it won't work as expected.

Comment: Tnx for correction, but even after the change. the issue is still the same

Comment: Have you added the rows in the database again after the correction. because otherwise your ids would have been same. Also can you share what is getting printed. are you getting 5 same rows printed or only 1 row the last one

Comment: but when im running another method...this prints all rows but only once..

ie when i delete all the rows and while adding them freshly

Comment: when you do getAllContacts, what does it print?

Comment: Look @ the new ans i have provided

Comment: the one that has  db.deleteContact(con);

Comment: Thanks a lot bro...u have spoted my issue out...yes my deleteContact logic was wrong, thats why in SqlTable only one row was being saved. Hence i was getting one result out....Really Sorry my bad.

Comment: No problem man. Happy to help. Adding the comment as an answer so that you can accept :)

Answer (score 0):

At first Rectify Your **Constructor** Section . set **`id`** <kbd>**int**</kbd> type .

```
 private int _id;
```

Then

```
 public SqlContact(int id, String description, String message, String status, String timestamp, String type)
        {

            this._id = id;
            this.description= description;
            this.message= message;
            this.status= status;
            this.timestamp= timestamp;
            this.type= type;

    }
```

And

```
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int _id){
    this._id = id;
}
```

**Wrong Statement**

```
SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase(getApplicationContext());
List<SqlContact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
```

**It should be**

```
SqlDatabaseNotification db = new SqlDatabaseNotification (getApplicationContext());
List<SqlContact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
```

Comment: @RajivReddy According to your question, `this.setDescription(getId());` is wrong

Comment: @RajivReddy You should put your ID `int ` instead of `String` .`int id, String description `

Comment: @RajivReddy check my edited answer .Uninstall old app and run again

Comment: i have updated my ans...But i have same issue still...pls check if anything is wrong

Comment: well i am using that only...i edited that to not confuse ppl, sorry i forgot apply it here

Comment: @RajivReddy Don't call `SqlDatabase ` . Call `SqlDatabaseNotification ` .I hope it will fix your problem

Comment: i am using                     SqlDatabaseNotification db = new SqlDatabaseNotification(getApplicationContext()); this is not the issue

Comment: @RajivReddy Tried my best level .Check is there any sloppy mistake

Comment: Thanks a lot mate for trying to help me.....i found out the issue....my deleteContact logic was wrong,  thats why in SqlTable only one row was being saved. Hence i was getting one result out

Comment: @RajivReddy Kindly review this answer if helped

Answer (score 0):

Usage and Logic of Method `db.deleteContact(con);` was Wrong, Hence corrected, and issue resolved.

Thanks to Everyone who Helped and took time to answer my question.